# What does "%" (percent) do in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, syntax

It seems that the % operation starts script blocks after the pipeline, although [about_Script_Blocks](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847893.aspx) indicates the % isn't necessary.

These all work just fine.

```
get-childitem | % { write-host $_.Name }

{ write-host 'hello' }

% { write-host 'hello' }
```

But when we add a script block after the pipeline, we need to have the % first.

```
get-childitem | { write-host $_.Name }
```

Comment: You might also have tried Get-Help %

Comment: @mjolinor That's useful. I didn't know I could get help on symbols. I see that we can also lookup $_ with get-help. That's great!

Comment: Why the close vote? I would like to improve the question.

Comment: It's also a modulus operator! just not in this context

Comment: @Cole9350 That's a useful item to add to the current answer.

Comment: One thing it doesn't do that cmd / batch files used to do is surround environment variables and provide string expansion. cmd used to be able to do things like `echo %programfiles%` but in powershell you'd do `echo $Env:programfiles`

Comment: @mjolinor doesn't work on linux PS-with or without single/double quotes.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

When used in the context of a cmdlet (such as your example), it's an alias for `ForEach-Object`:

```
> Get-Alias -Definition ForEach-Object

CommandType     Name                                                Definition
-----------     ----                                                ----------
Alias           %                                                   ForEach-Object
Alias           foreach                                             ForEach-Object
```

When used in the context of an equation, it's the [modulus operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
> 11 % 5

1
```

and as the modulus operator, `%` can also be used in an [assignment operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847875.aspx) (`%=`):

```
> $this = 11
> $this %= 5
> $this

1
```

Comment: I will mark this as answer once it also contains the % role as a modulus operator in different contexts.

Comment: Added equation and assignment operator examples

Comment: In the case of Foreach-Object, I'd advise not using the "%" symbol - it makes it harder for folks to read/maintain your code - especially people new to PS.  Let's face it, the more people that pick up PS, the better.

Comment: Where can I find the ForEach-Object meaning in the official documentation on MSDN?

Comment: I disagree Simon Catlin, by that logic we should all be using assembly because the rest is just syntactic sugar

Comment: Another use of the percent symbol can't be simply replaced by ForEach-Object:
Get-ChildItem | % Name

Answer (score 24):

A post [PowerShell - Special Characters And Tokens](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens) provides description of multiple symbols including `%`

```
% (percentage)

1. Shortcut to foreach.
Task: Print all items in a collection.
Solution.
... | % { Write-Host $_ }

2. Remainder of division, same as Mod in VB.
Example:
5 % 2
```

Comment: @ShaunLuttin: The value is a link, which describes multiple special characters including %

Comment: Technically it's an alias for `ForEach-Object`. `ForEach` is also an alias for `ForEach-Object` - except when used at the start of a statement, where it's a loop control keyword (like `while`).

Answer (score 8):

`%` can replace `Get-ChildItem |` **`ForEach-Object`** `{ write-host $_.Name }` which will not work without either the `%` or the `ForEach-Object`.